# Delay when switching Controllers in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Has anyone else found a noticeable delay when requesting a view that is under another controller?

For example, all actions under the same controller seem to respond quickly, but when I follow a link that leads to another controller there is a lag - almost like it's compiling on the fly?

Answer (score 1):

Well, ASP.NET uses JIT compiling.  However, if this lag is consistently happening over and over, it may be another issue since once it's compiled the first time, it shouldn't recompile right away.